# How to make a countersink in Sketcher

Tags: mesh

I'm new at blender and i'm trying to "replicate" a product from work, that it's a plaque that has 4 holes in the corners. But the holes have a countersink for the screws.

Is there any way to make this in the [CAD Sketcher](https://www.cadsketcher.com/) Blender add-on, so that when I apply the modifier solidify, Blender can render that?

Thank you

Comment: I was refering to CAD Sketcher. An Add-on to use in blender. But thank you for your reply.

Comment: My apologies. I've edited your question to make that clear. The answer is yes (probably not with Solidify). Get as far as you can, and then edit your question if you get stuck.

Comment: thank you :) well i've tryed a lot of things but none work...like I sayd...im a noob :) all the help is welcome.

Comment: Please explain how far you have got so far,, what you have. You can share your effort as far as it's gone (or a toy version of it) on https://blend-exchange.com/ , if you like.